# Add array object not init

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

I have a method that init my class object from JSON. The method like this:

```
func getList (dic : Array<[String:AnyObject]>)  -> Array<Dog> {
    let dogs : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    for myDic in dic {
        let dog = Dog.init(dog: myDic)
        dogs.addObject(dog)
    }
    return NSArray(dogs) as! Array<Dog>
}
```

And I can present it on tableview without issue. But right now I want to make pagination for the list. If I run the method getList again it will be init new object and replacing my old one. How can I to add a new object to exisiting. I don't want to create separate object with the same property.

Comment: Just use Swift arrays, no need for Foundation collections anymore in Swift. Using an Array as input then using an NSMutableArray then converting to Array again makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a member variable which you will append to. So:

```
var dogs: [Dog] = []
```

And then call `getList` like this:

```
dogs += getList(dic: myDic)
```

By the way, you can make your `getList` method much simpler, like this:

```
func getList(dic: [[String: AnyObject]]) -> [Dog] {
  return dic.map(Dog.init)
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But probably `AnyObject` should become `Any` (in order to include `String(s)`, `Int(s)` and other structs without the need of a manual casting)

Comment: `AnyObject` was defined in the original question. We do not know if the `Dog` initializer has a particular reason for requiring a dictionary of `AnyObject` types.